# Holo Theme Backwards Compatibility for Action Bar tabs

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat

I am currently working on an application using the Holo theme and am targeting the minSdkVersion = 9. I have an action bar with tabs throughout the entire application that work from version 11+ and am wondering the best way to use backwards compatibility to get versions 9 & 10 to function correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com). This will give you a backwards compatible  ActionBar and ActionBar tabs.